# Slow update query on table with indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-update

I have 4 indexes on my table. When Im running update query like this

```
UPDATE table SET column_without_indexes = true;
```

It runs very slow, like more than 10 min for 700k rows.
But if I drop all indexes in table before running the query - it runs in 30sec.

I cant get it, why UPDATE query slows down with adding indexes on columns, which are not even being updated?

Comment: You update all records in this table, are you sure nobody else is locking one or more records? And don't forget that an update is actually a DELETE + INSERT, it has to create new index tuples in all indexes because of this.

Comment: "update is actually a DELETE + INSERT"

Really? I have a doubt about it.

Comment: @flgdev Yep... read the manual on concurrency control and MVCC, HOT updates, etc. I've written some more detailed explanations of this recently too; see http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/84802/7788

Comment: This is a dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/84802/7788; should migrate and close.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an UPDATE is a DELETE + INSERT.

If you want an example of this, take a table simple look up table (with a few records in it) and take the first record of the table and update it. Say something like:

```
update table set [col1] = [col1]
where table_id = ?
```

This should just be done to update a single record for the purpose of demonstration.

Then run a select on the table and you will see that this record which WAS at the top of the table is now at the BOTTOM.

This is the standard for how SQL handles and UPDATE.

It literally discards the OLD record and inserts a NEW record. It doesn't bother with messing around with an OLD record.

SO realize that when you are doing an update on all these 700k rows, it is doing a DELETE + INSERT for 700k rows and INDEXing them all newly and doing it all in one go (so it ends up holding a lot in memory as you are dealing with TRANSACT SQL - basically it holds everything in memory until it fully commits).

So maybe you can figure another way to do the update, or just to feed 10k rows at a time or something like this.